# Software to filter Windows 10/11 notifications based on string/regex?

Tags: windows, notification

I'm looking for a way to filter Windows 10/11 notifications based on their content, using a string match or even regex.

My current use case is that I'm on a Discord server that has a "firehose" channel that sends out a ton of messages that I get notifications for. Discord itself has no way to filter notifications based on their content, and the way this Discord server is set up, it's either all or nothing. I only care about messages that contain a few specific strings. Everything else I want to filter out.

Ultimately, I'm looking for something that can pattern-match my string/regex to show (or hide/dismiss) notifications. For Android there's [FilterBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.np). But I couldn't find anything similar for Windows.